# How to get all fields in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, formset

I have multiple classes with different number of fields inside them, 1 class example:

```
<div class="row form-row-extra-phone spacer">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="tel" name="extraPhone-0-phone_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Extra Phone Number" maxlength="128" id="id_extraPhone-0-phone_number">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                     <a class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm add-form-row" href="#" role="button" id="plus_payment_data">+</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to iterate on all the fields inside the classes that have the attribute "name" and "id" , and add 1 to the number inside (in the example `name="extraPhone-0-phone_number"` -> `name="extraPhone-1-phone_number"`)

I can select the class by:
`$('.form-row-extra-phone')`

How can I iterate on all the fileds ***inside*** it that contain the attributes 'name' and 'id'?

Comment: What do you mean "fields" ? what do you consider as a "field"? This question is't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `<div class="row form-row-extra-phone spacer">` when you speak about a `class`? This is an `element`, not a class.

Class can be a problematic term, because it can refer to CSS/DOM classes *or* Javascript classes, which are totally unrelated.

So if you have `<div class="something">` then `something` is a CSS/DOM class, but the entire thing is *not* that class but an `element` *having* that class.

Now also what you refer to by `fields` are also just `element`s.

So what you want is to select all elements that have the class `form-row-extra-phone` and of them all descendant elements with an `name` attribute. And thats pretty easy. Basically in a CSS selector the  (space) is the selector for descendant elements.

So you can select `.form-row-extra-phone [name]`.

So what you probably want is something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form-row-extra-phone [name]')
  .forEach(elem => elem.name.replace(/[0-9]/, x => Number(x) + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `^=` it means starts with, and `$=` means ends with.

If condition is (name AND id)

```
    $('.form-row-extra-phone input[name^="extraPhone"][id^="id_extraPhone"]')
```

If condition is (name OR id)

```
    $('.form-row-extra-phone input[name^="extraPhone"],input[id^="id_extraPhone"]')
```

check this https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ or google for "jQuery Multiple attributes selector"